# constexpr error at compile-time, but no overhead at run-time

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, c++14

There is a well-known trick to cause a compile-time error in the evaluation of a `constexpr` function by doing something like this:

```
constexpr int f(int x) {
    return (x != 0) ? x : throw std::logic_error("Oh no!");
}
```

And if the function is used in a `constexpr` context you will get a compile-time error if `x == 0`. If the argument to `f` is not `constexpr`, however, then it will throw an exception at run time if `x == 0`, which may not always be desired for performance reasons.

Similar to the theory of `assert` being guarded by `NDEBUG`, is there a way to cause a compile-time error with a `constexpr` function, but not do anything at run time?

Finally, do relaxed `constexpr` rules in C++1y (C++14) change anything?

Comment: I would have recommended using a *meta-function*, but since you are asking specifically for a resolution through a `constexpr` function, go on. Good question.

Comment: What should the function do instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: Here is a 33 page paper that discusses this issue in detail. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3583.pdf

Comment: @uk4321: Nothing. The runtime equivalent of just `return x` in my example.

Comment: Did you have something like this is mind: `constexpr int f(int x) {
    return (x != 0) ? x : reinterpret_cast<int>(x);
}`? It does a no-op if `x == 0`, but a `reintepret_cast` is not allowed in a constant expression (at least in C++11), therefore it will cause a compile-time error in the same way the throw-expression does. An even simpler way would be to use a function `g` which is no `constexpr` and returns the value for `x == 0`: `return (x!=0)?x:g(x);`

Comment: @DyP are you sure that works? I tried it and it never errors, maybe I did it wrong, or maybe gcc 4.8 is not correct: http://ideone.com/2iozle

Comment: @uk4321 Might be a g++ extension. clang++3.4 refuses it; also see 5.19/2, one of the last bullet points disallows using a `reinterpret_cast` in a constant expression.

Comment: @uk4321 Using the non-constexpr function variant (`constexpr int f(int x) { return (x != 0) ? x : g(x); }`, where `g` is a non-`constexpr` function) "works" also for g++4.8, in the sense that `constexpr auto x = f(0);` causes a compile-time error.

Comment: @DyP I would imagine that doesn't work if you don't assign the result to a `constexpr` variable, correct? I don't know if the OP was going to use it only in such scenarios.

Comment: The actual use case for this is in a constructor. I can accept that the checking won't be perfect, I'm just trying to do better than I am right now. My current situation is that I just declare something to be undefined behavior (and give users an alternative that does a runtime check when needed via `throw`). I'd like to do a compile-time check whenever I can, and I accept that in general you have to declare a variable `constexpr` for maximum static analysis.

Comment: @dyp compiles fine with clang 9.0.0 either. Also, the code OP posted does not throw in compile time too: neither with GCC nor with Clang.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Is there a way to cause a compile-time error with a `constexpr` function, but not do anything at run time?**

You can use the exact same trick, but instead of using a *throw-expression*, use an expression that is not a constant expression but does what you want at runtime. For instance:

```
int runtime_fallback(int x) { return x; } // note, not constexpr
constexpr int f(int x) {
  return (x != 0) ? x : runtime_fallback(0);
}

constexpr int k1 = f(1); // ok
constexpr int k2 = f(0); // error, can't call 'runtime_fallback' in constant expression
int k3 = f(0);           // ok
```

**Do relaxed `constexpr` rules in C++1y (C++14) change anything?**

Not in this area, no. There are some forms of expression that are valid in constant expressions in C++14 but not in C++11, but neither *throw-expressions* nor calls to non-`constexpr` functions are on that list.

Answer (score 3):

> If the argument to f is not `constexpr`, however, then it will throw an exception at run time if `x == 0`, which may not always be desired for performance reasons.

A function argument is never considered to be a constant expression. The distinction would require compile-time and runtime objects to have different types.

Even though the compiler is using pure functional semantics when it evaluates the function at compile time, it's still the same function with the same meaning. If you want another function of similar but different meaning, you will have to either define another entire function, or make a template.

You could use a signature like this:

```
template< typename int_type >
constexpr int f(int_type x);
```

with calls like this:

```
f( std::integral_constant< int, 0 >() ) // Error.
f( std::integral_constant< int, 3 >() ) // OK.
f( 0 ) // Not checked.
```

Metaprogramming can tell that `integral_constant` means a compile-time value. But I don't think it's really appropriate. If one sense of the function works with zero and the other doesn't, then you have two different functions.

A wrapper idiom could prevent duplication among the different functions:

```
constexpr int f_impl(int x) { // Actual guts of the function.
    return x;
}

int f(int x) { // Non-constexpr wrapper prevents accidental compile-time use.
    assert ( x != 0 && "Zero not allowed!" );
    return f_impl( x );
}

template< int x > // This overload handles explicitly compile-time values.
constexpr int f( std::integral_constant< int, x > ) {
    static_assert ( x != 0, "Zero not allowed!" );
    return f_impl( x );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
    // Suppresses unused variable warnings in release builds.
    #define ASSERT(X) (void(sizeof (X)))
#else
    #define ASSERT(X) ((X) ? void() : std::abort())
#endif

constexpr int f(int const x)
{
    return ASSERT(x != 0), x;
}
```

You can see the output [here](http://ideone.com/zFOlU5). If you add `constexpr` to the start of line 17 then you'll get a compile-time error instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `constexpr` function, you should use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert). This lets you run an assertion at compile-time that has zero runtime cost.

Comment: But his question is about when `x` (the parameter) is not known at compile time.

Comment: The `constexpr` may remain as it's harmless, but `static_assert` would replace the `throw`.

Comment: How would you do this? I can’t imagine how it would work without changing the interface.

Comment: You cannot use `static_assert` with `constexpr` function arguments.

Comment: @DavidStone No, but clearly the solution must use both `static_assert` and `constexpr`. See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most beautiful, but seems to work for my (slightly different) use-case. N.B. that I haven't tested it exhaustively, it may well not be perfect and am sharing in case it's of any help. Will happily take feedback:

```
// Arguments not guaranteed to be compile-time
constexpr bool singleDigitOnlyIsMultipleOfThree(const unsigned number){
    if ((number / 10) > 0)
        throw std::logic_error("ConstexprError");
    switch(number % 3){
        case 0:  return true;
        case 1:  return false;
        case 2:  return false;
        default: throw std::logic_error("Should be unreachable");
    }
}

// Both arguments and return value guaranteed to be compile-time
template<unsigned number>
constexpr bool singleDigitOnlyIsMultipleOfThree(){
    // Because number is constexpr, we guarantee we go through the above implementatio nas constexpr.
    return singleDigitOnlyIsMultipleOfThree(number);
}


int main(){

    constexpr bool   run1 = singleDigitOnlyIsMultipleOfThree(6);     // true
    constexpr bool   run2 = singleDigitOnlyIsMultipleOfThree(7);     // false
    const     bool   run3 = singleDigitOnlyIsMultipleOfThree(100);   // throws

    constexpr bool const1 = singleDigitOnlyIsMultipleOfThree<6>();   // true
    constexpr bool const2 = singleDigitOnlyIsMultipleOfThree<7>();   // false
    constexpr bool const3 = singleDigitOnlyIsMultipleOfThree<100>(); // does not compile

    cout << run1 << " " << run2 << " " << const1 << " " << const2 << endl;
    
}
```

This funciton should return a (potentially compile-time) value indicating if the argument is divisible by three, but not allow any value >= 10. When called using template arguments, we have a guaranteed constant expression. When using function brackets as a constant expression, we have a compile-time constant. When using function brackets as a runtime expression, then we will have an exception in lieu of a compiler error.

There is the advantage that we can implement the logic using a constexpr function, thus avoiding the need to do it the old-fashioned way using all template specialisation. So our code is faster to write, more succint, and more expressive. However, we can still call it at compile-time and enforce the constant nature of the output and generate a compile-time error. If we want to gamble with runtime values, then it should have behaiour to match. Major disadvantage is having two separate ways to call the function. If we really want to ensure it's a constant expression, then we need to use the angle-bracket syntax, or force assigning to a constexpr.

Answer (score -1):

This *seems* to do the trick. It is not very pretty, but the idea is to distinguish value that is available at compile time from one that isn't using SFINAE on constexprs. I can compile this with clang 3.3 and have the compilation fail when I try to use f(0) in a constexpr context, but not throw when I use it at runtime. You can probably create a one-parameter maybethrow overload that makes the (not_)preferred trick internal to its implementation.

```
struct not_preferred {};
struct preferred { operator not_preferred() { return not_preferred(); } };

template< typename T, T X >
T compiletime() { return X; }

template< typename T >
constexpr auto maybethrow( preferred, T x ) -> decltype( compiletime< T, x >() )
{
    return 0 ? x : throw 1;
}

template< typename T >
constexpr auto maybethrow( not_preferred, T x ) -> T
{
    return x;
}

constexpr int f(int x)
{
    return x ? x + 1 : maybethrow( preferred(), x + 1 );
}
```

Comment: A function parameter is never assumed to be a *constant expression*. Therefore I think the first overload of `maybethrow` is ill-formed (even though an early clang++3.4 accepts it).

Comment: @DyP You are right, I don't know what I was thinking. I'm also quite confused as to why would it work. I must have invoked something unintentionally, or my test code is bogus. The non-constexpr subroutine trick is much better anyway.