# How to prevent accidental emission of constexpr functions

Tags: c++14, constexpr

Ben Deane mentions [the throw trick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMB9oXFobJc&t=3m40s), which ensures a link error when a constexpr function is used in a non-constexpr context.

Here is my take:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Exc;

constexpr int foo( int a )
{
    if( a == 42 )
    {
        throw Exc{};
    }

    return 666;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr auto ret = foo(43);
    std::cout << ret << "\n";

    return ret;
}
```

But I couldn't make it work (clang++ 3.8.1-23 and g++  6.3.0):

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14  main.cpp 
main.cpp:9:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'ExcBase'
        throw ExcBase{};
              ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:3:8: note: forward declaration of 'ExcBase'
struct ExcBase;
       ^
1 error generated.
```

A comment in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461121/constexpr-error-at-compile-time-but-no-overhead-at-run-time) suggests another trick:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int foo( int a )
{
    if( a == 42 )
    {
        (void)reinterpret_cast<int>(a);
    }

    return 666;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto ret = foo(43);
    std::cout << ret << "\n";

    return ret;
}
```

Which works: no errors or warnings; when the invocation is replaced with `foo(42)`, clang returns:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 main.cpp 
main.cpp:19:20: error: constexpr variable 'ret' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr auto ret = foo(42);
                   ^     ~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:15: note: reinterpret_cast is not allowed in a constant expression
        (void)reinterpret_cast<int>(a);
              ^
main.cpp:19:26: note: in call to 'foo(42)'
    constexpr auto ret = foo(42);
                         ^
1 error generated.
```

Which is great. But gcc compiles the code happily in both cases. And now the question. How can a constexpr function be written in such a way, that it cannot be used in non-constexpr environments?

Comment: @marcinj sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you actually instantiate (call constructor) a struct which is of incomplete type. This trick you talk about requires any symbol which will not be found at link time. So instead of `struct` you may use `int`:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3df5207827c8888c

```
#include <iostream>

extern int Exc;

constexpr int foo( int a )
{
    if( a == 42 )
    {
       throw Exc;
    }

    return 666;
}


int main()
{
    // Compiles
    constexpr auto ret = foo(43);
    std::cout << ret << "\n";

    // This will show linker error as expected:
    // /tmp/ccQfT6hd.o: In function `main':
    // main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4c): undefined reference to `Exc'
    // collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    int nn;
    std::cin >> nn;
    auto ret2 = foo(nn);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Silly me. And Exc into an unnamed namespace to make sure no one produces a definition for it. Thanks a ton.